# MySQL @variable in prepare statement concurrency issue

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to write a store procedure in mysql which takes the input variables as criteria to choose which table be counted. And then will react according to the value.

e.g.

```
PROCEDURE `Function`(IN table_name varchar(10))
BEGIN
    SET @c2 = CONCAT ('Select count(*) into @count From ',table_name);
    PREPARE stmt from @c2;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

    IF @count > 0 Then
        doing something
    Else
        do something else
    End If

END
```

As far as I understand, @count value is stored in the session rather than local. Prepare stmt needs to use @var in order to access the value elsewhere within the store procedure.

Now I have an issue, When I have a number of executions calling this store procedure at the same time would cause concurrency issue.

Is there any solution to resolve the concurrency issue? or alternative to run a dynamic query without needing @var?

Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

There's a big difference between a stored procedure and a function. So please don't name your procedure function.

That aside, you have no problem. There's no concurrency issue. Like you said, user defined variables (the one with the @) have session scope. To run it somewhat "simultaneous", you'd have to do this in another session and there the variable would have another scope.